# why "weakly-referenced object no longer exists" error occurred?

Tags: python, mysql, python-telegram-bot

I'm making telegram bot, which is adding some messages to mysql database and then deleting them. When I use this bot only by myself I don't get any errors, but if I sending messages using second account and trying to do it at the same time, after 5-10 messages I get "weakly-referenced object no longer exists" error. I guess I somehow lose connection to mysql database but I don't understand why. That's the error.

```
2020-08-10 00:05:48,249 (util.py:68 WorkerThread1) ERROR - TeleBot: "ReferenceError occurred, args=('weakly-referenced object no longer exists',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\shit stuff\code stuff\projects\dota_tg_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/shit stuff/code stuff/projects/dota_tg_bot/tg_bot.py", line 47, in process_quiz_second_question
    db.add_answer(user_id, int(message.text), 2)
  File "C:\shit stuff\code stuff\projects\dota_tg_bot\database.py", line 129, in add_answer
    self.cursor.execute(add_answer_statement, (answer, date, user_id))
  File "C:\shit stuff\code stuff\projects\dota_tg_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\shit stuff\code stuff\projects\dota_tg_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 484, in _handle_result
    self._connection.unread_result = False
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/shit stuff/code stuff/projects/dota_tg_bot/tg_bot.py", line 136, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/shit stuff/code stuff/projects/dota_tg_bot/tg_bot.py", line 132, in main
    bot.polling()
  File "C:\shit stuff\code stuff\projects\dota_tg_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 427, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "C:\shit stuff\code stuff\projects\dota_tg_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 451, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\shit stuff\code stuff\projects\dota_tg_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 111, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "C:\shit stuff\code stuff\projects\dota_tg_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\shit stuff\code stuff\projects\dota_tg_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/shit stuff/code stuff/projects/dota_tg_bot/tg_bot.py", line 47, in process_quiz_second_question
    db.add_answer(user_id, int(message.text), 2)
  File "C:\shit stuff\code stuff\projects\dota_tg_bot\database.py", line 129, in add_answer
    self.cursor.execute(add_answer_statement, (answer, date, user_id))
  File "C:\shit stuff\code stuff\projects\dota_tg_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\shit stuff\code stuff\projects\dota_tg_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 484, in _handle_result
    self._connection.unread_result = False
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists

Process finished with exit code 1
```

That's class of mysql handler i use.

```
import mysql.connector
from config import DB_PASSWORD
from dota_parser import get_winrates, get_quiz_answers
import datetime


class MySQLDatabase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = None
        self.cursor = None

    def connect(self):
        self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            password=DB_PASSWORD,
            port='3306',
            database='dotatelegrambot'
        )
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def close(self):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.connection.close()

    def get_hero_answers(self, hero):
        self.connect()
        get_hero_answers_statement = ('SELECT Answer1, Answer2, Answer3 FROM heroes '
                                      'WHERE Hero = %s')
        self.cursor.execute(get_hero_answers_statement, (hero,))
        answers = self.cursor.fetchone()
        self.close()
        return answers

    def get_hero_winrates(self, hero):
        self.connect()
        get_winrate_statement = ('SELECT Winrate1, Winrate2, Winrate3, Winrate4, Winrate5 '
                                 'FROM heroes '
                                 'WHERE Hero = %s')
        self.cursor.execute(get_winrate_statement, (hero,))
        winrates = self.cursor.fetchone()
        self.close()
        return winrates

    def get_heroes(self):
        self.connect()
        get_heroes_statement = 'SELECT Hero FROM heroes'
        self.cursor.execute(get_heroes_statement)
        heroes = self.cursor.fetchall()
        self.close()
        return heroes

    def update_user(self, user_id, hero):
        self.connect()
        get_user_statement = ('SELECT UserID '
                              'FROM users '
                              'WHERE UserID = %s')
        self.cursor.execute(get_user_statement, (user_id,))
        user = self.cursor.fetchone()
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        date = f'{now.year}-{now.month}-{now.day}'
        if user:
            update_user_statement = ('UPDATE users '
                                     'SET CurrentHero = %s, LastDate = %s '
                                     'WHERE UserID = %s')
            self.cursor.execute(update_user_statement, (hero, date, user_id))
            self.connection.commit()
        else:
            add_user_statement = ('INSERT INTO users (UserID, CurrentHero, LastDate) '
                                  'VALUES (%s, %s, %s)')
            self.cursor.execute(add_user_statement, (user_id, hero, date))
            self.connection.commit()
        self.close()

    def get_user_hero(self, user_id):
        self.connect()
        get_user_hero_statement = ('SELECT CurrentHero '
                                   'FROM users '
                                   'WHERE UserID = %s')
        self.cursor.execute(get_user_hero_statement, (user_id,))
        hero = self.cursor.fetchone()[0]
        self.close()
        return hero

    def add_answer(self, user_id, answer, number):
        self.connect()
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        date = f'{now.year}-{now.month}-{now.day}'
        add_answer_statement = ('UPDATE users '
                                f'SET Answer{number} = %s, LastDate = %s '
                                'WHERE UserID = %s')
        self.cursor.execute(add_answer_statement, (answer, date, user_id))
        self.connection.commit()
        self.close()

    def get_user_answers(self, user_id):
        self.connect()
        get_user_answers_statement = ('SELECT Answer1, Answer2, Answer3 FROM users '
                                      'WHERE UserID = %s')
        self.cursor.execute(get_user_answers_statement, (user_id,))
        answers = self.cursor.fetchone()
        self.close()
        return answers

    def clear_answers(self, user_id):
        self.connect()
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        date = f'{now.year}-{now.month}-{now.day}'
        clear_answers_statement = ('UPDATE users '
                                   'SET CurrentHero = Null, Answer1 = Null, Answer2 = Null, Answer3 = Null, '
                                   'LastDate = %s '
                                   'WHERE UserID = %s')
        self.cursor.execute(clear_answers_statement, (date, user_id))
        self.connection.commit()
        self.close()


def main():
    db = MySQLDatabase()
    db.connect()
    db.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Bot code.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import random
from config import TG_TOKEN, DOTA_RANKS
from database import MySQLDatabase

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TG_TOKEN)
db = MySQLDatabase()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Hi, I\'m dotabuff bot.')
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'What do you want to do?', reply_markup=welcome_keyboard())


@bot.message_handler(commands=['quiz'])
def start_quiz(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Choose hero:', reply_markup=heroes_keyboard())
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_quiz_choose_hero)


def process_quiz_choose_hero(message):
    if cancel_check(message):
        hero = message.text
        user_id = int(message.from_user.id)
        db.update_user(user_id, hero)
        msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'What is starting move speed of {hero}?',
                               reply_markup=quiz_answers_keyboard(db.get_hero_answers(hero)[0]))
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_quiz_first_question)


def process_quiz_first_question(message):
    if cancel_check(message):
        user_id = int(message.from_user.id)
        hero = db.get_user_hero(user_id)
        db.add_answer(user_id, int(message.text), 1)
        msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'What is starting attack speed of {hero}?',
                               reply_markup=quiz_answers_keyboard(db.get_hero_answers(hero)[1]))
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_quiz_second_question)


def process_quiz_second_question(message):
    if cancel_check(message):
        user_id = int(message.from_user.id)
        hero = db.get_user_hero(user_id)
        db.add_answer(user_id, int(message.text), 2)
        msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'What is starting attack range of {hero}?',
                               reply_markup=quiz_answers_keyboard(db.get_hero_answers(hero)[2]))
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_quiz_third_question)


def process_quiz_third_question(message):
    if cancel_check(message):
        user_id = int(message.from_user.id)
        hero = db.get_user_hero(user_id)
        db.add_answer(user_id, int(message.text), 3)
        correct_ans = 0
        for ans_num in range(3):
            correct_ans += db.get_hero_answers(hero)[ans_num] == db.get_user_answers(user_id)[ans_num]
        if correct_ans != 1:
            bot.send_message(user_id, f'Congratulations!!! You have exactly {correct_ans} correct answers.',
                             reply_markup=welcome_keyboard())
        else:
            bot.send_message(user_id, f'Congratulations!!! You have exactly {correct_ans} correct answer.',
                             reply_markup=welcome_keyboard())
        db.clear_answers(user_id)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['winrates'])
def start_wr_check(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Choose hero:', reply_markup=heroes_keyboard())
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_hero_winrate)


def process_hero_winrate(message):
    if cancel_check(message):
        hero = message.text
        reply = ''
        heroes_winrates = db.get_hero_winrates(hero)
        for i, rank in enumerate(DOTA_RANKS):
            line = f'{rank} — *{str(heroes_winrates[i])} %* \n'
            reply += line
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, reply, parse_mode='Markdown', reply_markup=welcome_keyboard())


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'Cancel ⛔️')
def menu(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'What do you want to do?', reply_markup=welcome_keyboard())


def welcome_keyboard():
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('/winrates', '/quiz')
    return markup


def heroes_keyboard():
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('Cancel ⛔️')
    heroes = db.get_heroes()
    for hero in heroes:
        markup.add(hero[0])
    return markup


def quiz_answers_keyboard(correct_answer):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('Cancel ⛔️')
    answer_buttons = [types.KeyboardButton(correct_answer)]
    int_ans = int(correct_answer)
    for _ in range(2):
        rand_answers = [x for x in range(int_ans - 45, int_ans - 4, 5)] +\
                    [x for x in range(int_ans + 5, int_ans + 46, 5)]
        rand_ans = rand_answers.pop(random.randrange(len(rand_answers)))
        answer_buttons.append(types.KeyboardButton(rand_ans))
    random.shuffle(answer_buttons)
    for button in answer_buttons:
        markup.add(button)
    return markup


def cancel_check(message):
    if message.text == 'Cancel ⛔️':
        bot.clear_step_handler_by_chat_id(message.from_user.id)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'What do you want to do?', reply_markup=welcome_keyboard())
        return False
    return True


def main():
    bot.polling()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So every time I need to take or input data in database I open connection and after it I close it. (There is a lot of non problem related stuff use Ctrl+F "db" to follow database methods calls.)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gPwA.jpg
That's the structure of db for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with database related python's stuff, but I've seen in your code that every method you defined in MySqlDatabase creates a new instance of the database connection.
Are you sure you don't need to check if there is no connection open - to avoid instantiating a new one?

Here is how I would do:

```
   def connect(self):
       self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(
           host='localhost',
           user='root',
           password=DB_PASSWORD,
           port='3306',
           database='dotatelegrambot'
       )

   def getCursor(self)
       if not self.connection:
           self.connect()
       return self.connection.cursor()

   def get_user_hero(self, user_id):
       cursor = self.getCursor()
       get_user_hero_statement = ('SELECT CurrentHero '
                                  'FROM users '
                                  'WHERE UserID = %s')
       cursor.execute(get_user_hero_statement, (user_id,))
       hero = cursor.fetchone()[0]
       cursor.close()
       return hero
```

Comment: But in the end of every method I call "close" method which closes connection to databse so in every method I need to open new connection.

Comment: Yes, you do. I can only suggest to check the concurrent execution of MySQLDbs methods. If first thread start first method which instantiate connection and create a cursor and go into SQL execution and then from second thread the same or different method is called which recreate connection and cursor and go into SQL execution. If at this moment first thread finishes SQL and closes the cursor and connection - the second thread after back from SQL execution will try to close a closed cursor and the same for a connection. Maybe check how many threads have access to  instance stored in db